# Embedding a SWF in PowerPoint with VSTO

Tags: flash, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

I was wondering if there is someway to embed a Flash Shockwave Object or .SWF file in PowerPoint (Presentation)  2007 and higher version, i.e. inside the ".pptx" format. By embed I mean when I save the presentation,close it . i wont be needing the the .swf file again. That way I can share the presentations with others.

If I use this link [Insert-Flash-Into-PowerPoint-2007](http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Flash-Into-PowerPoint-2007),it works but when I save and 
close the presentation, the swf file doesn;t get embeded. (*Note*: If i do the same with a .ppt file, it works correctly)

I know we can embed the swf inside PowerPoint presentation version 2003, i.e. the ".ppt" format. but couldn't do the same in .pptx format.

Also is it possible to embed .swf file in .pptx using Open XML format? I tried to rename the ".pptx" file to ".zip" and added the ".swf" in media folder and then renamed it back to ".pptx", but when opened in PowerPoint, it gave an error about unreadable content or corruption.

I had read somewhere that its kind of strategy from MS not to provide this kind of support for Adobe SWF file / ActiveX object and as of now the feature is not supported. [Flashppt PPTX Embed not supported](http://www.flashppt.com/blog/2008/04/cannot-embed-flash-movies-in-powerpoint.html)

I tried the same with Office 2010 and still the same result. It doesn't work.

Does anyone have any workarounds?

Related links:

- [Insert-Flash-Into-PowerPoint-2007](http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Flash-Into-PowerPoint-2007)
- [flashgeek](http://www.flashgeek.com/tutorials/02_embed_01.asp)
- [support.microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291875)
- [Flashppt PPTX Embed not supported](http://www.flashppt.com/blog/2008/04/cannot-embed-flash-movies-in-powerpoint.html)

Comment: so it sounds like you just want to use the PPTX for storage of the SWF, is that correct? do you need to try to play the SWF from within PPT?

Comment: yes correct.also need to play the SWF when put on slide.
(as is the case with .PPT )

Comment: I've looked into this some more, it doesn't appear possible. I'll let you know if I find out something different back on this thread.

Comment: thx  ..i will keep checking :) ..i will update this is if any progress.

Comment: It looks Like 'embedding' a SWF in a PPT is somewhat similar to embedding a SWF in an html page, only PPT uses ActiveX control. In html, if you don't have the swf file on the system, the embed code will be a broken reference. I think it's pretty similar with PPT.

Comment: @Amtid: does the answer below answer your question?

Comment: @Amtid: what do you mean? the answer is just simply "it can't be done in PowerPoint 2007". however, it *can* be done in PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: Oh ok.
Using Open XML or PowerPoint 2010 VSTO?
any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in PowerPoint 2007.